# Eigenvalues of GCD matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Fix $n\ge 1$ and let $A=(\gcd(i,j))_{1\le i,j\le n}$. It is known that $\det A=\phi(1)\dots\phi(n)$.

I'm intrested in knowing more about the eigenvalues of $A$. Can anyone point at a good reference?

Thanks.